# Docker Nextcloud Failed to load Collabora Online - please try again later

Tags: php, docker, document, nextcloud, collaborative-editing

I have this error message:

> Failed to load Collabora Online - please try again later

at the top-right corner of the self hosted nextcloud website when I try to open the file

> Welcome to Nextcloud Hub.docx

In Nextcloud that is running as a docker container.

**Welcome to Nextcloud Hub.docx** is located in **Files > Documents** as an example file.

[image: screenshot]

I am using the official image of [nextcloud:19-apache](https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud)
that I started this way:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e;
set -f;

docker run -d \
--name nextcloud \
-p 8080:80 \
-v /tmp/nextcloud/var/www/html:/var/www/html \
-v /tmp/nextcloud/var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
-v /tmp/nextcloud/var/lib/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
nextcloud:19-apache

sleep 3;

firefox "http://localhost:8080"

exit 0;
```

And I check logs this way:

```
docker logs nextcloud
```

There are no errors/warnings besides this one entry:

> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully
> qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName'
> directive globally to suppress this message

Clicking in nextcloud web Settings > apps shows that both apps required for Collabora are installed:

[image]

However there is no status of them if they are running as they should or not.

The status of all of the running container:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
88efc7e2489f        bridge              bridge              local
b75e841984e3        host                host                local
efff0416acdb        none                null                local


-------------------------------------------------------------

CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                CREATED              STATUS   IP                  PORTS                                            NAMES
58c7069e0a4d  nextcloud:19-apache  2020-09-21T13:59:53  running  bridge:172.17.0.2   map[80/tcp:[map[HostIp:0.0.0.0 HostPort:8080]]]  /nextcloud
```

How to make Collabora working and open that document docx?
(there is no problem when opening *.pdf or *.md files, edit them and have saved with a revision history)

Comment: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

This is not bad and normal if you are not working with a real domain. So only local. I will write you a Docker-Compose File this evening which makes more sense somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I took a look at this. I have always used Nextcloud only by Docker-Compose, Traefik or Nginx and the Colabora Server as extra Server.

1. **For Collabora to work, the Apache server must
   listen inside on port 9980.** For it to do so you would have to put the Apache
   Config revise (ProxyPass). See on Part2 in the Documentation [Link](https://nextcloud.com/collaboraonline/)
2. I cannot recommend the local Collabora Server because it is often crashes. But that's not the point here.
3. I wouldn't do it that way at all, but rather use docker-compose to assemble the service.

I have implemented a local installation of Nextcloud with Collabora via the Traefik Proxy. You don't have to worry about the webserver redirecting to the right port because Traefik takes care of that.

**Docker-Compose Example**

If you have any questions, just ask!

In my example I use Local Domains that resolve to the Docker IP. Just edit the Hosts file. But you know that for sure...

`192.168.x.x collabora.local.com`
`192.168.x.x nextcloud.local.com`

Install Docker-Compose if you do not already have it.

Create Networt "web":
`$ docker network create web`

Create Docker-Compose file:
`$ touch docker-compose.yml`

Add:

```
version: "3.3"

volumes:
  db:
  nextcloud:

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.3"
    container_name: "traefik"
    restart: always
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
    networks:
      - web
      - internal

  nextcloud:
    image: "nextcloud:19-apache"
    container_name: "nextcloud-app"
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - traefik
      - db
    volumes:
      - "nextcloud:/var/www/html"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud-app.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud-app.rule=Host(`nextcloud.local.com`)"
    networks:
      - web
      - internal

  collabora:
    image: "collabora/code"
    container_name: collabora-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - "9980"
    environment:
      - domain=nextcloud.local.com
      - extra_params=--o:ssl.enable=false
      - username=admin
      - password=admin
    cap_add:
      - MKNOD
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.collabora.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.collabora.rule=Host(`collabora.local.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.collabora.loadbalancer.server.port=9980"
    networks:
      - web

  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: nextcloud-db
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOSTNAME=maria_db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Secure_Root_Password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=Secure_Password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - "db:/var/lib/mysql"
    networks:
      - internal
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"

networks:
  web:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false
```

start: `docker-compose up`

start as deamon: `docker-compose up -d`

stop: `docker-compose down`

Comment: Can you share an example docker compose file you use for running the Nextcloud with Collabora? I am not bound to use Apache at all. I've just taken the Apache image because I thought I would be the fastest to get the Nextcloud with Collabora running but since there are problems with it it would make no difference to me if I used Apache or ie Nginx

Comment: thank you for sharing the docker-compose.yml I have problem when running `docker-compose config` - the error I see: `ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.nextcloud.depends_on contains an invalid type, it should be an array` I am using `docker-compose version 1.17.1, build unknown`

Comment: Sorry Docker-Compose Version dont support condition. Please change to `depends_on: - traefik - db` And maybe you do an update from time to time Current is version 1.27.4

Comment: do you know why this docker-compose file creates `docker_internal` network instead of `internal`. I don't have any problem with creating `internal` named network with `docker network create --internal internal` but docker-compose creates `docker_internal` the other funny thing is that `docker-compose up` complains when there is no `web` network but creates by itself that `docker_internal` network and removes it with `docker-compose down` so why it treats `web` network differently?

Comment: I have a problem with the current docker-compose.yml you provided as an example. At the machine the docker is running the nextcloud application is available under the network `web:172.xxx` but not from any other machine at the same local network 192.xxx but the traefik dashboard webpage at 8080 is available from the hosting machine and all the other machines at the same 192.xxx network. That's exactly the opposite state I would like to have. I would like the nextcloud app be available from the host and all ohters and treafik dashboard only from host. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Change you the hosts on the other clients to `SERVER_IP nextcloud.local.com` and flush dns.

Comment: The other thing I see is that accessing `localhost:8080` i get webpage with text `404 page not found` and no `Server` header (I would expect header `Server: Apache`) so my guess is that traefik does not forwad this request to the Apache server of the Nextcloud app - could I be right?

Comment: If you want your traefik to redirect to port 8080 you have to tell him so. For this purpose you use a loadbalancer service. ex.: `- "traefik.http.services.watch-port-80.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"` in the nextcloud section.

Comment: Actually I would like it to forward to the Nextcloud app that is under `172.xxx.xxx.xxx:80` do you know what rule I would need to put to traefik?

Comment: `- "traefik.http.services.watch-port-80.loadbalancer.server.port=80"`

Comment: It should be enough to specify the server IP not the internal Docker IP...

Comment: But the traffic only knows what to do if you address it with the domain you have specified. You can't choose localhost, 172 or whatever you have to specify the host in the browser it is also specified here `app.rule=Host(YOUR-HOST)`